# Sub domain with digitalocean + Amazon Route + Hostgator

Tags: subdomain, cname-record, dns-zone, amazon-route53, digital-ocean

I have two domains, www.domain1.com and www.domain2.net.
www.domain1.com is hosted by digitalocean
www.domain2.net is hosted by hostgator shared plan. (website hosting)

The zone file of www.domain1.com is managed by Amazon Route5
The zone file of www.domain2.net is managed by hostgator

What I need is a subdomain www.democracy.domain1.com
The website or webapp than must be load in www.democracy.domain1.com is hosted in www.domain2.net. I don't need a redirect, the client must be always in the domain domain1.com. It must be transparent for the client.

In Amazon Route5 I create a entry in the zone file:

democracia.dominio1.com. CNAME  www.dominio2.net.- - 300

I don't know if is possible to do what I want, in that case, what entry can add in the zone file in hostgator?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

`www.democracy.domain1.com.` CNAME `www.domain2.net.` is correct with trailing dot to indicate TLD.

Now the hard part ensure the web-server is set to listen on `www.democracy.domain1.com` this is probably restricted by host-gator / cpanel in the config and is bound to your DNS and will probably require reaching out to their support.